# passport.initialize() middleware not in use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am using node, express, mongoose and passport for my project and I implemented a simple Log In functionality to my code as seen below in app.js and it works perfectly. I then tried to split my code because I want to use MVC and this time when I run my application and try to log in I get the passport.initialize() middleware not in use Error. I have tried everything that other users in other posts have suggested but to no avail. Any suggestions?

**app.js - old one which works**

```html
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Donation = require('./models/Donation');
const User  = require('./models/User');
const donationRoutes = require('./routes/donationRoutes');
const registerRoutes = require('./routes/registerRoutes');

// express app
const app = express();

// connect to mongodb & listen for requests
const dbURI = "mongodb+srv://test:test@test.8npff.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(result => app.listen(3000))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// register view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// middleware & static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

// express setup for login
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressSession = require('express-session')({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressSession);

// passport setup for auth login
const passport = require('passport');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport local authentification
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

/* LOGIN ROUTES */

const connectEnsureLogin = require('connect-ensure-login');

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local',
  (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/login?info=' + info);
    }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      return res.redirect('/');
    });

  })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/login',
  (req, res) => res.render('login', {title: 'login'})
);

app.get('/donations',
  connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn(),
  (req, res) =>  {
    Donation.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .then(result => {
        res.render('donations/index', { donations: result, title: 'All Donations' });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
);

app.get('/user',
  connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn(),
  (req, res) => res.send({user: req.user})
);

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

//Register Routes
app.use('/', registerRoutes);

// *** routes ***
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/donations');
});

//donation routes
app.use('/donations', donationRoutes);

// 404 page
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).render('404', { title: '404' });
});
```

**app.js - new one**

```html
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const donationRoutes = require('./routes/donationRoutes');
const registerRoutes = require('./routes/registerRoutes');
const loginRoutes = require('./routes/loginRoutes');

// express app
const app = express();

// connect to mongodb & listen for requests
const dbURI = "mongodb+srv://test:test@test.8npff.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(result => app.listen(3000))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// register view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// middleware & static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

//Register Routes
app.use('/', registerRoutes);

//Login Routes
app.use('/', loginRoutes);

// *** routes ***
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/donations');
});

//donation routes
app.use('/donations', donationRoutes);

// 404 page
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).render('404', { title: '404' });
});
```

**loginController.js**

```html
const connectEnsureLogin = require('connect-ensure-login');
const Donation = require('../models/Donation');
const express = require('express');
const User  = require('../models/User');
// express app
const app = express();
// express setup for login
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressSession = require('express-session')({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressSession);

// passport setup for auth login
const passport = require('passport');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport local authentification
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

const login_post = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local',
  (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/login?info=' + info);
    }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      return res.redirect('/');
    });

  })(req, res, next);
}

const login_get = (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', {title: 'login'});
}

const index_get = (req, res) => {
  connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn();
  Donation.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })
  .then(result => {
    res.render('donations/index', { donations: result, title: 'All Donations' });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

const user_get = (req, res) => {
  connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn();
  res.send({user: req.user});
}

const logout_get = (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/')
}

module.exports = {
  login_post, 
  login_get, 
  index_get, 
  user_get,
  logout_get
}
```

**loginRoutes.js**

```html
const express = require('express');
const loginController = require('../controllers/loginController');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', loginController.login_post);
router.get('/login', loginController.login_get);
router.get('/donations', loginController.index_get);
router.get('/user', loginController.user_get);
router.get('/logout', loginController.logout_get);

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the error log:

```html
Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\123\Documents\Datenbanken_Projekt\transparent_blood\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:46:34)
    at C:\Users\123\Documents\Datenbanken_Projekt\transparent_blood\controllers\loginController.js:43:9
    at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\Users\123\Documents\Datenbanken_Projekt\transparent_blood\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:219:18)
    at verified (C:\Users\123\Documents\Datenbanken_Projekt\transparent_blood\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)
    at C:\Users\123\Documents\Datenbanken_Projekt\transparent_blood\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:205:41
```

Comment: You have to reuse the `app` variable from `app.js`. You cannot create another express app in `loginController.js` that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. You create new `app` more than once. First in `app.js`, then in `loginController.js`. You should use just one instance of app, otherwise it's like a second server and your middleware won't work properly.
2. In your example, you **never** initialize passport (using `passport.initialize()`). In the first sample (that is working), there are many lines of passport initialization, including strategies and stuff - everything after `// passport setup for auth login`. Then they're gone. You need to bring them back ;)

Comment: I accidentally pasted the app.js code in loginController.js as well. I added the right code now, but still I have created a new app in there as well. As I am new to node and express I did not consider the fact that I should only have one instance. Any tipps on how I could export app to use it in loginController as well?

Comment: You typically have just one `app.js` file, where you initialize the application and add routes. In the routes handlers, there you use your controller (and you don't modify app itself). You just use the router (which is okay to reuse everywhere). So on your controller, you should just have request handlers (from `login_post` onwards). That's good enough I think :)